# phpmyadmin bug: edit insert

Tags: phpmyadmin

The edit functionality of phpmyadmin stopped working today. Whenever I click the little pencil right next to a row, it redirects me to insert and all the fields are empty. Has sb experienced something like that before?

Comment: It's unlikely to be a bug. check the mysql permissions on the account phpmyadmin uses to talk to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bug in that version of phpMyAdmin. To edit a record without upgrading/downgrading phpMyAdmin select the row(s) you want to edit and click the 'change' button at the bottom of the results table.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. It cleared after restarting the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the php session folder is writable by the web server, in my case ( /var/lib/php/session/)